# Checking user role on a hooked function breaking website in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-roles

I am trying to add a tab to the My Account page if a specific user exists. 
I created a `check_user_role` function that checks if a specific role exists. 
If the `premium_member` role exists an extra tab should be added to the My Account page.
Right now when I add the `check_user_role` function it breaks my website.
Everything is in the `functions.php` file

```
function check_user_role($roles, $user_id = null) {
  if ($user_id) $user = get_userdata($user_id);
  else $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if (empty($user)) return false;
  foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    if (in_array($role, $roles)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// ------------------
// 1. Register new endpoint (URL) for My Account page
// Note: Re-save Permalinks or it will give 404 error
  
function vehicle_intake_form_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'vehicle-intake-form', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'init', 'vehicle_intake_form_endpoint' );
  
// ------------------
// 2. Add new query var
  
function vehicle_intake_form_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'vehicle-intake-form';
    return $vars;
}
  
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'vehicle_intake_form_query_vars', 0 );
  
// ------------------
// 3. Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu
if(check_user_role(array('premium_member'))) {
    function vehicle_intake_form_link_my_account( $items ) {
        $items['vehicle-intake-form'] = 'Vehicle Intake Form';
        return $items;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'vehicle_intake_form_link_my_account' );
}
// ------------------
// 4. Add content to the new tab
  
function vehicle_intake_form_content() {
   echo '<h3>Premium WooCommerce Support</h3><p>Welcome to the WooCommerce support area. As a premium customer, you can submit a ticket should you have any WooCommerce issues with your website, snippets or customization. <i>Please contact your theme/plugin developer for theme/plugin-related support.</i></p>';
   //echo do_shortcode( ' /* your shortcode here */ ' );
}
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_vehicle-intake-form_endpoint', 'vehicle_intake_form_content' );
```

Comment: Did you check the error logs? what error did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `If` statement needs to be **inside** the function, never outside it.

You can use [`current_user_can()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/), but **inside** your hooked function like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'vehicle_intake_form_link_my_account' );
function vehicle_intake_form_link_my_account( $items ) {
    if( current_user_can('premium_member') ) {
        $items['vehicle-intake-form'] = __('Vehicle Intake Form');
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Or use `check_user_role()` revisited function to be used inside your hooked function like:

```
function check_user_role( $roles, $user_id = null ) {
    $user = $user_id ? new WP_User( $user_id ) : wp_get_current_user();

    if ( is_a($user, 'WP_User') && count( array_intersect($roles, $user->roles) ) > 0 ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'vehicle_intake_form_link_my_account' );
function vehicle_intake_form_link_my_account( $items ) {
    if( check_user_role( array('premium_member') ) ) {
        $items['vehicle-intake-form'] = __('Vehicle Intake Form');
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: This exact solution came to my head write after I wrote this post. I realised what I was doing wrong.